# Learning Resources for Recommendation system

Tags: recommender-system, beginner

Beginner here:

Could you please suggest some of the learning resources (books/youtube/articles) for beginners who want to build a recommendation system for their organization.

*Have no clue about it except for Amazon and Netflix example.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a technical background, I would certainly recommend the chapter 9 from [Mining Massive Datasets by Jure Leskovec](http://www.mmds.org/#book). Video lecture of the topic is also available there. Look for chapter 9. [This blog](https://medium.com/recombee-blog/machine-learning-for-recommender-systems-part-1-algorithms-evaluation-and-cold-start-6f696683d0ed) could also give you some overall insight.

Please keep in mind that, ML-wise, recommendation is a more creativity-related topic than other classic questions like Classification or Regression and indeed all those classic problem could be a step in building a reasonable recommender engine.

Comment: oh yes, they are amazing authors, I have seen their videos on youtube; Standford University faculties, its really a must.